# Python Polars: prefixing columns names while unnesting

Tags: python, python-polars

in a Polars dataframe I do multiple call to a complex function that returns a dictionary for different setups that is then unpacked into the dataframe.
I would like to prefix the names of the nested columns so they do not create duplicate columns.

Here is an example python code

```
import datetime
import random
import polars   as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'datetime_local': pl.Series(
        datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0) + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=20 * i) for i in range(500)
    ),
    'value1': pl.Series(random.random() for _ in range(500)),
    'value2': pl.Series(random.random() for _ in range(500))  
})

def my_complex_function(param_a:float, param_b:float, param_c:float, param_d:float):
    """ takes n parameters perform complex calculations and return a dictionary"""
    output_1 = param_a + param_b + param_c + param_d # you have to imagine that there are some complex calculations here
    output_2 = param_a * param_b * param_c * param_d
    output_3 = param_a / param_b / param_c / param_d
    return {"output_1": output_1, "output_2": output_2, "output_3": output_3}

setup_A_param_c_value = 1.0  
setup_A_param_d_value = 2.0

setup_B_param_c_value = 3.0
setup_B_param_d_value = 4.0

# Etc...

df = df.with_columns([pl.struct(['value1', 'value2'] ).apply(lambda x: \
              my_complex_function(param_a=x['value1'     ], param_b=x['value2'], \
                                  param_c=setup_A_param_c_value, param_d=setup_A_param_d_value, \
              ) ).alias('setup_A_results')]).unnest('setup_A_results')

df = df.with_columns([pl.struct(['value1', 'value2'] ).apply(lambda x: \
              my_complex_function(param_a=x['value1'     ], param_b=x['value2'], \
                                  param_c=setup_B_param_c_value, param_d=setup_B_param_d_value, \
              ) ).alias('setup_B_results')]).unnest('setup_B_results')
```

There the second call to the function will of course generate a duplicate error

I have found a dirty fix which is to pass the prefix to my function but this is not a clean way to do it.
There must be a way to prefix the nested columns names with a string.

Comment: There are a few issues on the tracker regarding this e.g. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9613

Answer (score 0):

The only workaroune I have found for now is to pass the prefix to the function to generate the right names to unpack. ir is not very nice but at least it works.

```
def my_complex_function(param_a:float, param_b:float, param_c:float, param_d:float, prefix_name:str="prefix"):
    """ takes n parameters perform complex calculations and return a dictionary"""
    output_1 = param_a + param_b + param_c + param_d # you have to imagine that there are some complex calculations here
    output_2 = param_a * param_b * param_c * param_d
    output_3 = param_a / param_b / param_c / param_d
    return {f"{prefix_name}_output_1":output_1,
            f"{prefix_name}_output_2":output_2,
            f"{prefix_name}_output_3":output_3,}
```

This allows multiple calls of the functions to unpack in different columns by adapting the prefix.

Once the Polars issues on this subject mentioned by general-grievance are resolved maybe we can have a nicer looking solution